# WHERE IF statement ALL SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have an issue which I can not find anywhere. It is a strange scenario.

Imagine:

```
DECLARE @P INT
SET @P = 5
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID = @P --THIS WILL SELECT 1 ROW.
```

But if `@P` is null, I don't want it to do this.

Now one could do

```
 IF @P IS NULL BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM tbl
 ELSE
     SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID = @P
 END
```

But when you have a very big select script 50 lines, you don't want to repeat it twice.

It would be far easy to do something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ID IN ISNULL(@P, *)   -- if "*" returns everything
```

Can you do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (@P IS NULL OR ID = @P);
```

Comment: You're a god. It is a simple as that, saved tons of code. I did try Coalesce and couldn't get it working, I would get 1 row and no rows for all.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario which might be more readable if you have many things in your Where clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ID = Coalesce(@P, ID)
```